# Android - How to store an image inside the Firestore folder which is already created

Tags: java, android

```
public void upload() {
    if(imageUri!=null) {
        StorageReference reference=storageReference.child("customers/");
        reference.putFile(imageUri).addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<UploadTask.TaskSnapshot>() {
            @Override
            public void onSuccess(UploadTask.TaskSnapshot taskSnapshot) {
                // Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"File Uploaded",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
        }).addOnFailureListener(new OnFailureListener() {
            @Override
            public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception e) {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),e.getMessage(),Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
        }).addOnProgressListener(new OnProgressListener<UploadTask.TaskSnapshot>() {
            @Override
            public void onProgress(UploadTask.TaskSnapshot taskSnapshot) {
                double totalProgress=(100*taskSnapshot.getBytesTransferred())/taskSnapshot.getTotalByteCount();
                // Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"File uploaded"+(int)totalProgress,Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
        });
    }
}
```

In Firebase storage, there is one folder called "customers" where I want to store the selected image. When I try to upload the image, it is storing it as a different folder, not the folder which is already created. Here, "customers" is the already created folder.

Comment: Hello @deepa please go through this example i think it will help you.

https://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/image-upload-to-firebase-in-android-application--cms-29934

Comment: k thanks for sending link

Comment: can u please tell me what is UUID.randomUUID().toString()

Comment: The UUID.randomUUID() method is used to retrieve a type 4 (pseudo randomly generated) UUID. The UUID is generated using a cryptographically strong pseudo random number generator.

Comment: k i modified the reference like this ("customers/"+ UUID.randomUUID().toString())

Comment: Thank you for sending link now its working

Comment: now i want to know how to post the name of the file inside that folder

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
public void upload(String imageName) {
    if(imageUri!=null) {
        StorageReference reference=storageReference.child("customers).child(imageName);
        reference.putFile(imageUri).addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<UploadTask.TaskSnapshot>() {
            @Override
            public void onSuccess(UploadTask.TaskSnapshot taskSnapshot) {
                // Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"File Uploaded",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
        }).addOnFailureListener(new OnFailureListener() {
            @Override
            public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception e) {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),e.getMessage(),Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
        }).addOnProgressListener(new OnProgressListener<UploadTask.TaskSnapshot>() {
            @Override
            public void onProgress(UploadTask.TaskSnapshot taskSnapshot) {
                double totalProgress=(100*taskSnapshot.getBytesTransferred())/taskSnapshot.getTotalByteCount();
                // Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"File uploaded"+(int)totalProgress,Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
        });
    }
}
```

In order to retrieve the image name use:-

```
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
        Uri selectedImageUri = data.getData( );
        String picturePath = getPath( getActivity( ).getApplicationContext( ), selectedImageUri );
        Log.d("Picture Path", picturePath);
        upload(picturePath);

    }
}

public static String getPath( Context context, Uri uri ) {
    String result = null;
    String[] proj = { MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA };
    Cursor cursor = context.getContentResolver( ).query( uri, proj, null, null, null );
    if(cursor != null){
        if ( cursor.moveToFirst( ) ) {
            int column_index = cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow( proj[0] );
            result = cursor.getString( column_index );
        }
        cursor.close( );
    }
    if(result == null) {
        result = "Not found";
    }
    return result;
}
```

Comment: I hope this helps !

Comment: can u please tell what is that imageName

Comment: imageName is the name of the image by which image has to be stored in firebase storage.
In case of customers, the imageName can be a customer id (unique).

Comment: i want to store the selected image name.how to get that name

Comment: I have updated my answer. Have a look @deepa. But I think you should name your image as a unique id rather than a image name. It will be easy for you to update the image with unique id.

Answer (score 0):

Try to get file from this file, it could be because of incorrect reference to your folder. Also show code where is your `getReference()` method is called or it is better how you set reference to your FirebaseStorage.